# How to implement autocomplete and lexing in ScintillaNET

Tags: c#, scintilla

I'm trying to implement java autocomplete in one of my ScintillaNET projects and am having an issue. I've been following all the steps required

- Ensure that ScintillaNET (and required .dlls) are located in my PATH variable.
- Added the CustomLocation and Language params values to my editor

Below is my code for review, and I have ensured that I have the params set correctly...I'm just lost.

```
Scintilla sciEditor = (Scintilla)selectedTab.Controls["sciEditor"];
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sciEditor.Text = line;
            }
            if (ext == "java")
            {
                sciEditor.ConfigurationManager.Language = "java";
                sciEditor.ConfigurationManager.CustomLocation = @"C:\java.xml";
                sciEditor.CharAdded += new EventHandler<CharAddedEventArgs>(sciEditor_CharAdded);
            }
```

So you can see I read the text into the Scintilla editor, and if the files ext is java (which I parse above this block, and get valid answer), then I set the editors languaget to java, and set my custom location to a java.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScintillaNET>
  <Language Name="java">
    <AutoComplete FillUpCharacters=".([" SingleLineAccept="True" IsCaseSensitive="False">
      <List>
        abstract assert boolean break byte case catch char class continue default do double else enum extends
        final finally float for if import int interface long native new package private protected public return
        short static strictfp super switch synchronized this throw throws transient try void volatile while
      </List>
    </AutoComplete>

    <Indentation TabWidth="4" SmartIndentType="cpp" />

    <Lexer LexerName="java" LineCommentPrefix="//" StreamCommentPrefix="/* " StreamCommentSuffix=" */" >
      <Keywords List="0" Inherit="False">
        abstract assert break case catch continue default do else extends final finally for if import interface
        native new package private protected public return strictfp super switch synchronized this throw throws
        transient try volatile while
      </Keywords>
      <Keywords List="1" Inherit="False">
        boolean byte char class double enum float int long short static
      </Keywords>
    </Lexer>
  </Language>
</ScintillaNET>
```

And whenever I deploy (and have the .xml in my C:\ folder (or deployed beside my executable) it doesn't apply any styling (and the autocomplete is empty). Besides downloading and recompiling my own, I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me today and I got banned for asking such a question.
Shame on ScintillaNET developer(s).
Trying to define myself a custom language, but, ended up you can't do it.
So, what I did is I used pre-built language as a NAME, and then extended that LANGUAGE instead of defining my own, which ScintillaNET cant find. Hopefully you understand, it took me four days to figure it, such a stupid shit. Thanks to Charles:) - dreamincode.net for a hint, as my head is blown atm.